# Formatting issues with Heatmap.2 function in gplots library - margins and axis

Tags: r, heatmap

I've created a heatmap in R using the heatmap2 from the gplots package and I am having awful trouble trying to format the image for use in a report.

The image represents the eigenvalues of a small correlation matrix of wavelet coefficients and I wish to represent the largest eigenvalues with a strong colour such as red and smallest using a soft yellow or similar. The colour palette isn't so much the issue it's the representation of the colours. Currently yellow represents the largest eigenvalue so I wish to reverse the order if possible.

Also is it possible to rotate the legend similar to the first image below, I've checked the help for such info but all I can find is row and column label rotation?

[image: Ideal legend]

Since my data represents a week's worth of data taken every hour, how can I change the x-axis values to show the following 12/24hr vector: 12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120,132,144,156,168. I tried setting this using cexCol but I got an error about cex.axis having the wrong length and I don't see this as an argument in heatmap2.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
heatmap.2(eigenvalsCombined,
          trace = "none",
          dendrogram = "none",
          Rowv = NULL,
          Colv = NULL,
          density.info = "none",
          margin = c(5,7),
          main = expression(paste("Heatmap of Largest Eigenvalues ",
                                  lambda[1], 
                                  " Across 7 Wavelet Scales")),
          xlab = "Time Index (hours)",
          key = TRUE,
          lmat = rbind(c(2,3),c(4,1)),
          key.title = NA,
          key.xlab = "Eigenvalue Magnitude")
```

As you can see from my image below the main title is also chopped off, I have tried playing with the outer and inner margins but this doesn't have any impact either. When I use the zoom feature in the plotter and blow up the image the text appears, does this mean my formatting is correct?

[image]

For those interested in the data, I have posted a copy of the dput(eigenvalsCombined) to [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgkBr1CkDf7ODBCV2licE0zSUE/view?usp=sharing) for download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find the solutions for some of your problems.

```
# (1) Define column names of data matrix following your 12/24hr vector
clnames <- rep("",ncol(eigenvalsCombined))
sq <- seq(12,168,12)
clnames[sq] <- sq
colnames(eigenvalsCombined) <- clnames

# (2) Reverse your color map
rev.heat.colors <- function(n) rev(heat.colors(n)) 

library(gplots)
#par(mfrow=c(1,1))

heatmap.2(eigenvalsCombined,
          trace = "none",
          dendrogram = "none",
          Rowv = NULL,
          Colv = NULL,
          density.info = "none",
          margin = c(5,7),
          main = "",
          xlab = "Time Index (hours)",
          lmat = rbind(c(5,2,3),c(6,1,4)),
          lwid = c(0.2, 4, 1.1),
          lhei = c(0.5, 4),
          key = TRUE,
          key.xlab = "Eigenvalue Magnitude",
          col = "rev.heat.colors",
          cexCol=1.2)

# Add title to the plot
title(main=expression(paste("Heatmap of Largest Eigenvalues ",
           lambda[1],  " Across 7 Wavelet Scales")))
```

This is the plot generated by the code:

[image]

**EDIT**
I modified the `heatmap.2` function and now the colormap is rotated according to your needs.
First, download the file `myheatmap2.r` from this [link](https://pastebin.com/0wLg00vy) and save it in your working directory.
Then, run the following code:

```
clnames <- rep("",ncol(eigenvalsCombined))
sq <- seq(12,168,12)
clnames[sq] <- sq
colnames(eigenvalsCombined) <- clnames   
rev.heat.colors <- function(n) rev(heat.colors(n))

library(gplots)
source("myheatmap2.r")
myheatmap.2(eigenvalsCombined,
          trace = "none",
          dendrogram = "none",
          Rowv = NULL,
          Colv = NULL,
          density.info = "none",
          margin = c(5,7),
          main = "",
          xlab = "Time Index (hours)",
          lmat = rbind(c(2,3,6),c(4,1,5)),
          lwid = c(0.8, 4, 0.5),
          lhei = c(0.5, 4),
          key = TRUE,
          key.title="",
          key.xlab = "Eigenvalue\n Magnitude",
          col = "rev.heat.colors",
          cexCol=1.2)

title(main=expression(paste("Heatmap of Largest Eigenvalues ",
           lambda[1],  " Across 7 Wavelet Scales")))
```

Here is the final plot:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I think your column names solution is fantastically simple and brilliant and thank you for tidying up the alignment, it was driving me nuts trying to understand how the plotting window is arranged as a matrix. This has been a massive help, thank you once again. I will accept the legend as is and move on with my life ; )

Comment: thank you once again, you are a gentleman! I am really grateful to you for taking the time to find the solution to my problem. That has been a tremendous help to me, thank you once again.

Answer (score 4):

For tasks like this I am a fan of calling either `image` or using the `fields` package. To me there is no value added for using `gplots` and `heatmap2` on a task like this.

```
library(fields)

sq <- c("", seq(12,168, 12))

par(mar=c(3.1,5.1,4.1,7.1), xpd=TRUE)
image(t(eigenCombined), col = rev(heat.colors(100)), 
            xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlim=c(-0.15,1),
      main=expression(paste("Heatmap of Largest Eigenvalues ",
                                                    lambda[1], " Across 7 Wavelet Scales")))
axis(4, at = seq(0,1, length.out = 7), 
     labels = rownames(eigenCombined), lty = 0, las=2)

axis(1, at = seq(0,1, length.out = length(sq)), 
     labels = sq, lty = 0, las=2)

image.plot(t(eigenCombined), legend.only = TRUE,
           col = rev(heat.colors(100)), 
           smallplot = c(0.05,0.1, 0.1,0.85))
```

[image]